# Constant modification compiler error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, constants

In Visual Studio 2015 running the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int a = 0;
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

**obviously** generates a compiler error, however the error is:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

I accept that the code should generate a compiler error, but this wording doesn't make much sense to me, since the left-hand side of the assigment (`a`) is a variable - an integer variable (that happens to be a constant)

How comes that my `a` variable isn't recognized as a variable?

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a const. If I remember correctly, it gets compiled or JITed to `0` wherever used instead of `a`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Updated question with full code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That error message is right.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) says:

> Constant fields and locals aren't variables

So the constant isn't one of *variable, property or indexer*.